# want to cover full page using this animation how this is possible

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animations

I am making a water filling animation. My questions are

1. How can I make it responsive.
2. Are there any changes I need to make to the SVG.
3. It's currently positioned at the start of the page in the top left corner, and I want to show it full page.

My code is below.

```css
#banner {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}

#banner .fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}

@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}

@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner" align="center">
  <div align="center">
    <svg xml:space="preserve">
      <g class="fill">
        <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
    c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
    c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show my animation to cover the full page, how is this possible.

Comment: Absolute position, top, left, right, bottom all zero?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to give the SVG a viewBox. You can then give the div 100% width and height.

```css
#banner {

  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  z-index: -1;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
#banner .fill {
  animation-name: fillAction;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.2, .6, .8, .4);
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
#banner #waveShape {
  animation-name: waveAction;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  fill: #04ACFF;
}
@keyframes fillAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 150px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -5px);
  }
}
@keyframes waveAction {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-150px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="banner" align="center">
  <div align="center">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" preserveAspectRatio="none" xml:space="preserve">

        <g class="fill">
          <path fill="#04ACFF" id="waveShape" d="M300,300V2.5c0,0-0.6-0.1-1.1-0.1c0,0-25.5-2.3-40.5-2.4c-15,0-40.6,2.4-40.6,2.4
c-12.3,1.1-30.3,1.8-31.9,1.9c-2-0.1-19.7-0.8-32-1.9c0,0-25.8-2.3-40.8-2.4c-15,0-40.8,2.4-40.8,2.4c-12.3,1.1-30.4,1.8-32,1.9
c-2-0.1-20-0.8-32.2-1.9c0,0-3.1-0.3-8.1-0.7V300H300z" />
        </g>


    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```